# MYSQL Update using inner join cross using two tables issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I'm trying to set a post to trash based on the title from another column in another table. Below is the code I have been trying to use, but so far the solution escapes me:

```
UPDATE egDuqUe_5_posts
SET egDuqUe_5_posts.post_status = 'trash'
FROM
egDuqUe_5_posts
INNER JOIN 
egDuqUe_7_posts.id = egDuqUe_7_wc_order_coupon_lookup.coupon_id
WHERE
egDuqUe_5_posts.post_title = egDuqUe_7_posts.post_title
```

Comment: *I'm sure I'm missing something simple* You simply miss that this syntax is not legal. [UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) - there is no FROM clause. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: Also, where this table `egDuqUe_7_wc_order_coupon_lookup` comes into picture. It is just used in join but not included anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

After a cup of tea, I came to this solution:

UPDATE egDuqUe_5_posts m

JOIN
egDuqUe_7_posts s
ON m.post_title = s.post_title
JOIN
egDuqUe_7_wc_order_coupon_lookup c
ON c.coupon_id = s.ID
SET m.post_status = 'trash'
WHERE m.post_type ='shop_coupon' && m.post_title = s.post_title